# How to save a random variable string?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I call the following randomstring to create names in fields. 
How do I store the name given to "x" user, to use the same random created variablein the rest of my test? For example, create, edit, delete.

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the `Random` class with its [`Random(int Seed)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_) constructor.

This will produce the same set of numbers every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global variable and access this variable in your other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your string in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings variable, since it exists all time, while exists test class, you can have access to it from all tests of that class.

```
using System.Configuration;

public static string UserName
        {
            get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]; }
            set { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"] = value; }
        }
```

So you can set it in your first test and access from other tests.